# Positioning of selected p values using ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, p-value, ggpubr

I am using the mtcars dataset as an example to run the below code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggboxplot(mtcars, x = "cyl", y = "drat", fill = "cyl", 
          facet.by = "am", width = 0.5, outlier.shape = NA, 
          bxp.errorbar = TRUE, bxp.errorbar.width = 0.2) + 
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = ifelse(p < 1.e-4, 
                                        sprintf("p = %2.1e", as.numeric(..p.format..)), 
                                        sprintf("p = %5.4f", as.numeric(..p.format..)))), 
                     method = "wilcox.test", paired = FALSE)
```

I am having trouble modifying this to achieve the following. In each facet, I would like add only two wilcox.test p values, one comparing `cyl=4` to `cyl=6` and one comparing `cyl=4` to `cyl=8`. Then, I would like each of these p values to be located above the `cyl=6` and `cyl=8` boxes, respectively.

I love using the `ggsignif` package, but I need to extrapolate this example to 9 comparisons, which makes `ggsignif` less suitable (the comparison bars take up too much space).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add the 'library'. Now added in the edited version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to compare each other group to the "reference" group, `cyl=4`. If you use the `ref.group` argument to `stat_compare_means` it should give you what you want:

```
ggboxplot(mtcars, x = "cyl", y = "drat", fill = "cyl", 
          facet.by = "am", width = 0.5, outlier.shape = NA, 
          bxp.errorbar = TRUE, bxp.errorbar.width = 0.2) + 
    stat_compare_means(
        aes(label = ifelse(p < 1.e-4, 
                           sprintf("p = %2.1e", as.numeric(..p.format..)), 
                           sprintf("p = %5.4f", as.numeric(..p.format..)))), 
        ref.group = "4",
        method = "wilcox.test", paired = FALSE
    )
```

Comment: Wow, that's terrific! Surprisingly simple. Thank you very much, Marius.